# m_hWnd member variable is null

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to get the handle of a dialog box with this code:

```
class CStatisticsDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CStatisticsDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_STATISTICS };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
};

CStatisticsDlg::CStatisticsDlg() : CDialogEx(CStatisticsDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CStatisticsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FUCK, m_fuck);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStatisticsDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

But when I create an instance of the class with this:

```
CStatisticsDlg statisticsDlg;
```

and try to get its handle via `statisticsDlg.m_hWnd`, the handle is null.

Why this is the case? What is the best way to get the handle for a dialog box?

Comment: When do you try to get the handle? It probably doesn't get created until the dialog is displayed.

Comment: After i call statisticsDlg.DoModal();

Comment: After you call it and the call returned? Then the dialog no longer exists and there is no window handle any more.

Comment: what do you mean by 'call returned'?

Comment: actually the answer below explains what call returned means.

Answer (score 3):

The first point during the creation process where you can get the m_hWnd is the dialog's OnInitDialog function. The m_hWnd does not exist before the DoModal call and does not exist after the DoModal returns.

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried calling statisticsDlg.OnInitDialog() after statisticsDlg.DoModal(), but this results in a Debug Assertion Error.

Comment: How do i call OnInitDialog if 'The m_hWnd does not exist before the DoModal call and does not exist after the DoModal returns'??

Comment: You don't call OnInitDialog, MFC will call it when the dialog is created. Add a message handler in the dialog for WM_INITDIALOG. And..get a book or a tutorial. You are thrashing around with no idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

try modalless dialog model .Use `create` function instead of `domodal`.m_hWnd does not exist before `create` call begins.